# How to send an email to a specific user using emailJS in reactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, email

I want to send quotations to specific users that have made a shipment in my react website. I am using emailjs, but it doesn't seem to be working. **I want a non server-side way to do this.**

here is my code:

```
const {freight, creatorsEmail} = useLocation().state; //creatoresEmail is the email of the user i want to send the email to.

 function sendEmail(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    
     emailjs.sendForm(
         "xxxxx",
         "xxxxxx",
          creatorsEmail,
         "xxxxx"
     ).then((res) => {
         if(res){
             firebase.firestore().collection("Quotations").add({
                 costPrice:costPrice,
                 sellPrice:sellPrice,
                 creatorsEmail:creatorsEmail,
                 freight:freight
             }).then((result) => {
                 alert("Quotation Sent Successfully")
                 window.location.reload()
             }).catch((e) => {
                alert("An Error Occured, Quotation Cannot be Sent")
                console.log(e)
             })
         }
       
     }).catch((e) => {
         alert("There was a problem")
         console.log(e)
     })
  }

               <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                onclick={sendEmail} // in here would this be a correct way of calling the function sendEmail(e)?
              >
                Send Quotation
              </Button>
```

Comment: Try nodemailer its docs seem more easier

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril i want a non server side way to do this

Comment: I use [formspree](https://formspree.io/javascript) to accomplish things like this. Their [documentation](https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/articles/360053108134-How-To-Build-a-Contact-Form-with-React) on implementing with react is clear and easy to use!